# How to split a range of numbers considering other variables as well?

Tags: classification, statistics, algorithms, mathematics

Let's say that I have a vector of numbers and I'd like to split it into 3 most optimal ranges for example, then I suppose I can use k-means or Jenks natural breaks. If I'd like to do the same thing but with consideration of other variables, is there an algorithm for that? Splitting a vector of numbers into a number of classes w.r.t. other variables as well? Multivariate K-means won't work for this because it'd not yield ranges but classes.

Comment: Most of your question seem to indicate that clustering is what you're looking for, but the last sentence contradicts this by saying that you actually need to yield "ranges". Perhaps you should not focus your question on what you _think_ would lead you to progress, but on the bigger challenge from which you derived this question. Your question appears to call for a nonstandard, possibly convoluted requirement.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by "w.r.t. other variables"? What would be the expected outcome? Intervals as a function of the other variables? Convex polygones? Something else?